# Will the TextEditingController defined in TextField be disposed?

Tags: flutter

In case the `TextEditingController` was defined right in the `TextField` will it be disposed automatically on widget `dispose()`?

Does this apply to stateful and stateless widget?

```
TextField(
    enabled: false,
    controller: TextEditingController(text: 'sample'),
    ...
    ),
  );
```

Comment: I believe the implicit TEC created by TextFIeld will be completely managed by the TextField, and require no further action on your part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I check the documentation here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/controller.html, it said

```
**Controls the text being edited.
If null, this widget will create its own TextEditingController.**
```

This implies that if a TextEditingController is provided, it will be used to control the text and should be disposed by the framework when the TextField is disposed.